# Adding row with on click event

Tags: jquery

I have some issue with adding a row on a table with on click event 
I can only add one row.

```
 $('.add-result').on('click', function(event){
    console.log('click');
    event.preventDefault();
    var letter = $(this).closest('tr').find("input[name='key']").val();
    var thisRow = $(this).closest('tr');
    var nextLetter = nextChar(letter);
    $(thisRow).clone().insertAfter(thisRow).find("input[name='key']").val(nextLetter);
        $(this).remove();
  });
```

Here my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zp60wq1q/)

I don't know how to solve my problem

Comment: grammar, spellings and most important **code** .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`.clone(withDataAndEvents)`](https://api.jquery.com/clone/#clone-withDataAndEvents), a boolean indicating whether event handlers should be copied along with the elements

```
$(thisRow).clone(true)
```

[DEMO With Clone](https://jsfiddle.net/aqvdqa4c/)

---

Currently what you are using is called a "direct" binding which will only attach to element that exist on the page at the time your code makes the event binding call.

**As you are cloning elements and adding them** You need to use [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) using [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) delegated-events approach, when generating elements dynamically or manipulation selector (like removing and adding classes).

*General Syntax*

```
$(parentStaticContainer).on('event','selector',callback_function)
```

*Example*

```
$('.table').on('click', '.add-result', function(event) {
});
```

In place of `document` you should use closest static container.

> The delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. By picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the delegated event handler is attached, we can use delegated events to bind the click event to dynamically created elements and also to avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers.

A good read [Direct and delegated events](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events)

[DEMO with delegation](https://jsfiddle.net/w6ysL33c/)

Comment: Thanks a lot it help me a lot